# How to search for multiple strings in a dictionary values in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, search

I want to match multiple strings in a python dictionary which generally has only 1 key value pair. I'm looking for most optimized code, like a 1 liner.
Currently I'm trying with following code, but even if its working, I'm looking for a 1 liner

```
a = "increment"
b = "variable"
c = "found"
s = {'d':'want to increment the location variable based on which x is found'}

if any(a,b,c in value for value in s.values()):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use nested `any()` and `all()` calls. One for searching `s.values()`, the other for searching for each of `a, b, c`.

To make it a one-liner, just print the value of the call:

```
print(any(all(x in value for x in (a,b,c)) for value in s.values()))
```

This will print `True` or `False`.

If you really want `YES` or `NO`, use a conditional expression:

```
print('YES' if any(all(x in value for x in (a,b,c)) for value in s.values()) else 'NO')
```

Comment: I only care about `if any(any(x in value for x in (a,b,c)) for value in s.values()):` condition. But in your example, it is `TRUE` even if 1 of the string is matching, I want it to be `TRUE` only if all of the strings are matching.

Comment: Then use `all()` instead of `any()`.

Comment: perfectly working for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As per the author of the question, they intend to check if all the given elements are present in dictionary values. Hence, the code is updated to use `all()` instead of `any()`.

Here's a general solution if you want to check for all elements in a list `a`.

```py
a = ["increment", "variable", "found"]
s = {'d':'want to increment the location variable based on which x is found'}

print("yes" if all([(k in "".join(s.values())) for k in a]) else "no")
```